# C# chart using crosshair cursor

Tags: c#, charts, cursor

i'm working with C# chart class to display a curve. the type of the series is spline.
the thing would i do is show a crosshair cursor in the chart area. the vertical line of this cursor should move with the mouse when the mouse enter the chart. but the horizontal line should move whit the curve line not with mouse movement.
the code which i typed is here:

```
    private void chart1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point mousePoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SetCursorPixelPosition(mousePoint,false);
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.SetCursorPixelPosition(mousePoint,false);
     }
```

this code cause the cursor move whith the mouse and the result is like in this image:
[image]

to make the horizontal line of the cursor follow the curve line which is a sinusoidal signal here. i should know the Point of intersection between the vertical line of the cursor and the curve line. as this picture show:

[image]

is there any direct way to find this point? any help plz!.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the y pixel-offset relative to the top of the chart area if you know the following:

- `height` = Chart height in pixels
- `rangeMin/rangeMax` = Chart range min/max (here -150/150)
- `value` = function value (bottom image, approx. 75)

Taking the following formula:
`yOffset = height * (rangeMax - value) / (rangeMax - rangeMin);`

You should be able to plug `yOffset` into your MouseMove function like so:

```
private void chart1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    double yOffset = GetYOffset(chart1, e.X);
    Point mousePoint = new Point(e.X, yOffset);
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SetCursorPixelPosition(mousePoint,false);
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.SetCursorPixelPosition(mousePoint,false);
}

// ChartClass chart is just whatever chart you're using
// x is used here I'm assuming to find f(x), your value
private double GetYOffset(ChartClass chart, double x)
{
    double yOffset;
    // yOffset = height * (rangeMax - value) / (rangeMax - rangeMin);
    return yOffset;
}
```

Comment: i think it is impossible to find 'value' in my case.
thanks for your answer.

Comment: Do you know what the function it is that you're plotting? `f(x) = 100 * sin(x)` or something? Is there any way to poll the chart itself for the function? It may help if you post which chart class you are using, so I could go through the API.

Comment: i use chart class of .NET Framework 4.5 [ link ] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart(v=vs.110).aspx) and i'm not familiar withe other chart class.

actually i have no idea about the form of the curve i draw. because this curve in fact  is practical signal whose amplitude and form is large variant.
all the knowledge i have is  an array of sampling point for the signal.

Answer (score 0):

In this function I get the position of cursor X with the method `GetXOfCursor();`
after that I take the series point with this statement:

```
points = _theChart.Series[i].Points;
```

After with the last if statement I see the point that matches with the position X of the cursor
and I calculate the mean value of Y of this 2 Point because the point intercepted with the cursor is an interpolation line made by the windows chart control

```
public string GetPointInterceptedCursorX()
        {
            string values = string.Empty;
            // Far uscire le etichette ai punti intercettati
            var xPosCursor = GetXOfCursor();
            DataPointCollection points = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < _theChart.Series.Count; i++)
            {
                if (_theChart.Series[i].BorderWidth == ChartConst.THICKNESS_LINE_ENABLED)
                {
                    points = _theChart.Series[i].Points;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (points == null) return "No Curve Selected";
            for (int i = 0; i < points.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if ((xPosCursor > points[i].XValue & xPosCursor < points[i + 1].XValue) | xPosCursor > points[i + 1].XValue & xPosCursor < points[i].XValue)
                {
                    var Yval = (points[i].YValues[0] + points[i + 1].YValues[0]) / 2;

                    values += $"Y= {Yval} {Environment.NewLine}";
                }
            }
            values += "X=" + " " + String.Format("{0:0.00}", xPosCursor);
            return values;
        }
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. before writing an answer to questions, check their posted dates. begin your answer referencing the age of post if it is old (5 years in this case), and then describe the value of your answer for future use.